# I would like to transform an Excel calculation into a Python program with the same results

Tags: python, list, numpy, scheduled-tasks, numpy-ndarray

**A** represents tasks that need to be processed on each machine. A total of 5 tasks are given **T0 to T4**. 
**B** are the Setup values required to prepare a machine for processing a task that has been added before the task. Setup - **b0 to b3** represent values from the 'b' matrix.
Each task may have different values and must be processed on every machine (M0, M1, M2, M3). Machines - **M0 to M3** represent the maximum values calculated based on dynamic programming logic. 
The given program order list is used to specify the order in which rows from the a and b matrices should be processed on the machine. In this case, it starts with row 0 and goes up to row 4.

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[4, 3, 6, 2], [1, 4, 3, 5], [2, 5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 4, 1], [3, 6, 1, 4]])
b = np.array([[0, 2, 3, 1], [2, 0, 1, 3], [3, 1, 0, 2], [1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0]])
order = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
t = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]))

def calculate_matrix(order, a, b):
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        for j in range(a.shape[1]):
            if i == 0 and j == 0:
                t[i, j] = b[order[i], j] + a[order[i], j]
            elif i == 0:
                t[i, j] = b[order[i], j] + t[i, j - 1] + a[order[i], j]
            elif j == 0:
                t[i, j] = b[order[i], j] + t[i - 1, j] + a[order[i], j]
            else:
                t[i, j] = max(t[i - 1, j] + b[order[i], j], t[i, j - 1] + b[order[i], j]) + a[order[i], j]

    return t

final_matrix = calculate_matrix(order, a, b)
print(final_matrix)
```

Here's the Excel computation result t:

```py
[[4, 9, 18, 21], [7, 13, 21, 29], [12, 18, 23, 32], [18, 23, 29, 33], [23, 30, 34, 38]]
```

But I am getting a matrix from the given program

```py
[[4.  9. 18. 21.], [7. 13. 22. 30.], [12. 19. 24. 35.], [18. 24. 30. 36.], [23. 31. 35. 40.]]
```

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this question as a typo since your mistake is just that your `max` function call should be `max(t[i - 1, j], t[i, j - 1] + b[order[i], j])`. In case you're curious, here's another way of writing your code: https://hastebin.com/share/fiyadaxaxi.py

Comment: Minor change to my alternative solution: line 16 (`setup = np.zeros((a.shape[0]))`) is unnecessary and can be deleted.

Comment: Note that generally, we ask that question titles be not about what you're trying to do, but that they describe the narrow, specific technical problem that prevents you from doing it. (Similarly, the question itself should be written to focus narrowly on that problem, so someone who makes the same mistake writing a completely different kind of program can find your question and learn from its solutions; we're building a knowledge base, not a message forum).

Answer (score 1):

I've found two issues:

- I'm fairly sure that `t[i - 1, j]` ought to be referencing the `t[i - 1, j - 1]` cell.
- Both arguments to your max() reference the B matrix, but in the spreadsheet one of them references the A matrix.

Here's my best attempt. Take the line

```
t[i, j] = max(t[i - 1, j] + b[order[i], j], t[i, j - 1] + b[order[i], j]) + a[order[i], j]
```

and replace it with

```
x = t[i - 1, j - 1] + b[order[i - 1], j] + a[order[i - 1], j]
y = t[i, j - 1] + b[order[i], j]
z = a[order[i], j]
t[i, j] = max(x, y) + z
```

Output:

```
[[ 4.  9. 18. 21.]
 [ 7. 13. 21. 29.]
 [12. 18. 20. 32.]
 [18. 23. 29. 30.]
 [23. 30. 34. 38.]]
```

This is correct in all but two locations. I'm not sure why it's wrong in those places.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as caused by a typo as per my comment on the question.